# Google Places Autocomplete Details API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am in the process of making an android application with a location field so am using Google Places Autocomplete in order to assist the user.  Once they select a choice from the list, I am then getting the place_id from the response and using that to get the full address and coordinates.  However, I am seeing inconsistent results.  For example, if I have an address typed in I get the following in the response:

```
"place_id" : "ChIJhV00Saykj4ARf5pLLQUgXh8",
"reference" : "CkQ4AAAA6Oz4yvX3mdvSp_NuluEW-aMS5Kg6j0gNDxjidPUbnqsNrm17-Am4C8HwIBMfNXK20UvsrZt7MnJ1MeV3-N6kqxIQrIQn113f7ksZNBoX2NBVahoU4p6yZwFFSlTP5jZUXib5CO7uO5k",
```

If I use that place_id for a details request, I am missing the street_number, which was included in the previous response.  If I use the reference in the details request, then I get the correct location, with the street_number along with a different place_id.

```
"place_id" : "ChIJm5jeVKykj4ARICvBIsIA2MI",
```

After reading the docs, they said reference will be depreciated and I should use place_id but it is not working properly.  Does anyone know why or what is your solution for a place details request?